# Calculation by descending order

Tags: sql, ms-access

Input:

I have 5 columns in a table:

```
KONTO   COLLATERAL_TYPE   VALUE   COLLATERAL_VALUE LOST_probability
```

Example:

```
KONTO   COLLATERAL_TYPE   VALUE   COLLATERAL_VALUE LOST_probability
------------------------------------------------------------------
1            A            100           4               55%
1            B            100           40              5%
1            C            100           50              15%
2            A            200           50              55%
2            C            200           180             15%
2            B            200           120             5%
```

VALUE is overall value on single KONTO, and one KONTO can have few COLLATERAL_TYPEs.
I need to decrease VALUE staring with COLATERAL with lowest LOST_probability, and if COLLATERAL_VALUE is larger then  VALUE then return 0.
Calculation should be on single KONTO.

Output:

```
KONTO   COLLATERAL_TYPE   VALUE   COLLATERAL_VALUE LOST_probability CALCULATION
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            A            100           4               55%        6
1            B            100           40              5%         60
1            C            100           50              15%        10
2            A            200           50              55%        0
2            C            200           180             15%        0
2            B            200           120             5%         80
```

Formula:

CALCULATION(1) = VALUE - COLLATERAL_VALUE (by lowest LOST_probability)
CALCULATION(2) = CALCULATION(1) - COLLATERAL_VALUE (by 2nd lowest LOST_probability)

I use MS Access/SQL in MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
DLooklup("Value", "MyTable", "KONTO = " & KONTO & " AND LOST_probability = " & DMin("LOST_probability", "MyTable", "KONTO = " & KONTO)) - DSum("COLLATERAl_VALUE", "MyTable", "KONTO = " & KONTO & " AND LOST_probability <= " & LOST_probability)
```

`DLooklup("Value", "MyTable", "KONTO = " & KONTO & " AND LOST_probability = " & DMin("LOST_probability", "MyTable", "KONTO = " & KONTO))` looks up the value of the row with the lowest `LOST_probability` within the `KONTO`, you can replace it with `Value` if `Value` is always the same in a given `KONTO`.

`DSum("COLLATERAl_VALUE", "MyTable", "KONTO = " & KONTO & " AND LOST_probability <= " & LOST_probability)` substracts all `COLLATERAL_VALUE`s from all entries in the same `KONTO` with an equal or lower `LOST_probability`

This assumes all used columns in your table are valid numeric columns.

Note that this is a pure SQL approach. Computing this in VBA and outputting it to a table might speed this up.